# ssh-copy-id is copying my public key but I still need to enter my credentials when logging in to IAE

Tags: ibm-cloud, analytics-engine

I'm trying to setup passwordless ssh access to my cluster.

I've used `ssh-copy-id clsadmin@my-clusterhostname` and entered the cluster password when promoted.  The output from ssh-copy-id shows:

```
Number of key(s) added: 1
```

However, when I try to ssh into the cluster, I'm prompted for my password.  If I log in to the cluster, I can see the key has been added to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Why is passwordless ssh not working after these steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be because I had used a DSA key.  After creating a RSA key and copying that to the cluster, I was able to login over ssh without entering my credentials.